# Let $a, b$, be positives and $a \leq b$. For which $p$ the function $\frac{1} {x^a+x^b}$ is $L_p(0,+\infty)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

> Let $a, b$, be positives and $a \leq b$. For which $p$ the function $\frac{1} {x^a+x^b}$ is $L_p(0,+\infty)$?

I have solved without any problem the case $p=\infty$ (and it is not $L_p$ in this case) , but I can't solve the other case.

I suppose I have to use some inequalities but I have no idea which ones, and how.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: No idea at all? If you discuss $L_p$ spaces, I guess you know of elementary calculus, and then I think we could expect _some_ effort. Do you know for what values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ the integrals $\int_0^1 x^\alpha$ and $\int_1^{+\infty}x^\beta$ are convergent?

Comment: Yes of course but how can I split the main integral into those very simple integrals? There is a fraction!

Answer (score 0):

Since $b\geq a>0$ you will have
$$
\frac{1}{x^a+x^b}\approx \frac{1}{x^a}\quad\text{if }x\approx 0
$$
and
$$
\frac{1}{x^a+x^b}\approx \frac{1}{x^b}\quad\text{as }x\to+\infty.
$$
Now use comparison to make this argument complete.

Answer (score 0):

For $x \in (0,1)$ we have
$$x^a \le x^a+x^b \le 2x^a$$
so
$$\int_{(0,1)}\frac1{2^px^{ap}} \le \int_{(0,1)}\frac1{(x^a+x^b)^p} \le \int_{(0,1)}\frac1{x^{ap}}$$
Hence $\frac1{x^a+x^b}$ is in $L^p(0,1)$ if and only if $ap > 1$, or $p > \frac1a$.

Similarly, for $x \in (1, \infty)$ we have
$$x^b \le x^a+x^b \le 2x^b$$
so
$$\int_{(1, \infty)}\frac1{2^px^{bp}} \le \int_{(1, \infty)}\frac1{(x^a+x^b)^p} \le \int_{(1, \infty)}\frac1{x^{bp}}$$
Hence $\frac1{x^a+x^b}$ is in $L^p(1, \infty)$ if and only if $bp < 1$, or $p < \frac1b$.

Conclusion: $\frac1{x^a+x^b}$ is in $L^p(0, \infty)$ if and only if 
$$p \in \left(\frac1a, \frac1b\right)$$